# What tribe was Jehu from?

Tags: historical-figures, malchut-royalty, shevatim-12-tribes, genealogy, melachim-kings-book-of

From which tribe did [Jehu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jehu), King of Israel, descend?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From Menashe. See [Pesikta Rabbati 3](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pagefeed/hebrewbooks_org_39324_53.pdf)

> ובמלכים ירבעם בן נבט משל אפרים ואחרי כן יהוא בן (מנשה) [נמשי] משבט
>   מנשה